# Effect of np.random.seed(epoch) inside DistributedSampler.set_epoch()?

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing

Suppose I call `np.random.seed(epoch)` inside a PyTorch `DistributedSampler`’s `set_epoch(epoch)` method, what will happen?

```
    def set_epoch(self, epoch):
        np.random.seed(epoch)
```

Will that screw up the randomness of my samples?

Comment: I think it has no effect since NumPy and torch use different seeds.

Comment: NumPy and PyTorch have known problematic interactions. See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html and https://tanelp.github.io/posts/a-bug-that-plagues-thousands-of-open-source-ml-projects/